# How to have two while loops in a <table>?

Tags: php, html, html-table

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo"<fieldset style=width:300px;>
<center><table>
<table cellpadding=10;>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Room Number</th>

<th></th>

</tr>
</fieldset>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["firstname"] . 
"</td><td>" . $row["lastname"] .  
"</td>";
}
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
echo "</td><td>" . $row["roomnumber"] . "</td></td>" . "</td><td>";
}
echo "</table></center>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

How do I place all the results in a table? For the first result, both first and last name is displayed correctly under the header respectively, but however, for the second result, the room number is not displayed properly under the header but instead, displayed elsewhere.
How do I fix this?

Comment: In this case you can use a join for the 2 tables, no need to display 2 while loops.

Comment: Call the inner $row variable something else.

Comment: Or just use unset($row)

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL query could be done by using a JOIN like:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, r.RoomNumber
FROM Persons p
LEFT JOIN Rooms r ON r.PersonID=p.PersonID
```

Using a single query you will need a single `while` to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<?php
$i = 1;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo"<fieldset style=width:300px;>
<center><table>
<table cellpadding=10;>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Room Number</th>

<th></th>

</tr>
</fieldset>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["firstname"] . 
"</td><td>" . $row["lastname"] .  
"</td><td id=\"room_" . $i++ ."\"></td>";
}
echo "</table></center>";

echo "<script>
";
$i = 1;
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
echo "$('#room_" . $i++ . "').html('". $row["roomnumber"] ."');";
}
echo "</script>
";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex is correct would be better to fetch one result, or combine the arrays.

but this seems incorrect.

```
echo "</td><td>" . $row["roomnumber"] . "</td></td>" . "</td><td>";
```

shouldn't it be.

```
echo "<td>" . $row["roomnumber"] . "</td>" . "<td></td></tr>";
```

Also tablecell=10; is incorrect should be tablecell="10". center is deprecated.